# Failed to get downloadURL when uploading file in FirebaseStorage

Tags: swift, firebase-storage

I'm using FirebaseStorage in my Swift project for uploading images in a non public bucket.

Here are my rules:

In GoogleCloud Storage console:

```
allUser access has been removed
```

In FirebaseStorage console:
rules_version = '2';

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
        allow read: if request.auth != nil
      allow write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

With these rules, upload failed when trying to downloadURL:

```
let uploadTask = fileRef.putFile(from: url, metadata: metadata, completion: { (metadata, error) in
    guard let _ = metadata else {
        completion(nil,error)
        return
    }
                    
    fileRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
        completion(url,error) // <--- url is nil and error is set
        return
    }
})
```

Error is:

```
▿ Optional<Error>
  - some : Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13021 "User does not have permission to access gs://utw6xcl26d6ywvtosast/6309669a88262d10cea863e6/35B8D02C-476E-4B6D-A51D-501CC061F047.jpg." UserInfo={ResponseErrorDomain=com.google.HTTPStatus, data={length = 73, bytes = 0x7b0a2020 22657272 6f72223a 207b0a20 ... 2e220a20 207d0a7d }, object=6309669a88262d10cea863e6/35B8D02C-476E-4B6D-A51D-501CC061F047.jpg, NSLocalizedDescription=User does not have permission to access gs://utw6xcl26d6ywvtosast/6309669a88262d10cea863e6/35B8D02C-476E-4B6D-A51D-501CC061F047.jpg., bucket=utw6xcl26d6ywvtosast, data_content_type=application/json; charset=UTF-8, ResponseErrorCode=403, ResponseBody={
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission denied."
  }
}}
```

If I change rules in Firebase Storage to `read,write: if true` this is working but resource is accessible even without access token. Which is not I want.

Do you have an idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The user who uploads the file will have to have read access to that file in order to generate a download URL for it. Given your `allow read: if request.auth != nil` rule, it seems like the user is not authenticated.

You might want to authenticate the user (even if just with [anonymous sign-in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/anonymous-auth), which doesn't require them to enter credentials) and then for example to [allow them read/write access to files that are written under their own UID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/rules-conditions#user_private).